# Windows 10 won't wake from sleep for remote desktop

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, sleep, wake-on-lan

Windows 10 also won't run scheduled backups if it's sleeping. RDP and Acronis work properly if the computer is not asleep. Wake on LAN is enabled.

Comment: Do you have the power saving options on your nic disabled?  Make sure "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is not checked.  You can find this option under the Power Management tab located in your network interface properties.

Comment: Is WOL enabled both in the BIOS and in Windows? This might help: http://superuser.com/questions/696894/rdp-wake-on-lan-in-lan-environment

Comment: If you want that Windows 10 shall wake up for remote desktop you have to send a WoL magic package. With which method you send this WoL signal?

Comment: Check out the solution here as well https://superuser.com/questions/1020871/make-pc-wake-up-using-task-scheduler-in-win-10-from-sleep/1020905#1020905

Answer (score 4):

Click on (Start) or press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> key and type `device manager` and open the "Device Manager" window.

From here under "Network adapters" find the Ethernet Controller for which you would like to enable Wake-On-LAN (WOL).  Right-Click on that Ethernet Controller in the "Device Manager" window, to open the context menu and select "Properties".

From the Properties window select the "Power Management" tab, and make sure to enable:

- Allow this device to wake the computer

  - Only allow a magic packet to wake the computer

For some unknown reason, if both of these are not enabled then my machine would not wake.

Comment: Both activated, although the german translation is really strange and it's not obvious for me that "Aktivierung bei Musterübereinstimmung" is "Allow this device to wake the computer". I also believe this was working before the Version 1709 (Fall Creators Update) and is not working after that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Turn Remote Desktop power management to never sleep.

[image: Settins - Power & Sleep]

Comment: -1 That's not what the question is about.

Comment: This will consume a lot of energy for wrong reasons, I dont think this is the best solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with power management (display was not going to sleep) having everything configured correctly. I expect something like this may happen with WoL.

In my case executing power troubleshooter helped (while I returned back changes that it made).

Settings -> Update and Security -> Troubleshoot -> Additional troubleshooters -> Power.

I was using 'never sleep' option for PC and short sleep timeout for the display. Troubleshooter commented that sleep period for PC was too long, changed it to 1 hour, I returned to 'never' but display started to go to sleep correctly.

Hope this trick can help you with WoL but you also may find 'never sleep' approach useful. Modern hardware minimises power consumption to the minimum without OS even knowing it. Use simple wattmeter to check your case. For me WoL approach was just impossible - had no other stable device under my control within local network.

Answer (score 0):

The following guide from intel worked for me.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000027615/intel-nuc.html

1. Enable the wake on magic packet
   [image]
2. Change power management to allow device to be woken up
   [image]