# Disable RDP's Wake on LAN Feature

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop, wake-on-lan

As it seems, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/696894/rdp-wake-on-lan-in-lan-environment) is not up to date anymore.

After having forwarded the RDP port in my router and enabling WoL at my computer, I can remotely power on my shut down computer just by attempting to connect to it via RDP.

Just as a temporary fix until my VPN router arrives, is there any way to disable the computer to start when I try to connect with RDP **while** still letting me connect if it is already online?

Notes:

- A custom RDP port was set.
- This only works when the computer went to hibernation (not working after shutdown)
- Wake on LAN is enabled and should stay that way as I (temporarily) use a Raspberry Pi to wake the computer. This works, however, also RDP starts it up, which is exactly what I try to disable.

Comment: Disable WoL in the NIC's driver, via `devmgmt.msc`?

Comment: I would like to be able to start the PC via WoL, but only from the local network. When connecting via RDP over the internet, you should NOT be able to wake it up. Thus, I can't disable WoL.

Comment: Well, WoL is not a feature of the RDP protocol. It just happens that RDP protocol works over the networking protocol which has WoL enabled. So, the answer is probably no. What you can do is put something like Insteon / Samsung Smartthings etc. on the PC power plug, so you turn on the PC (via the plug), wait until it boots up and then connect. When you are done, cmd -> shutdown /h /t 0, wait for a few minutes and turn off the plug.

Comment: Maybe you could add this as an answer, it really seems as if that's the only solution or workaround :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, WoL is not a feature of the RDP protocol. It just happens that RDP protocol works over the networking protocol which has WoL enabled. So, the answer is probably no. What you can do is put something like Insteon / Samsung Smartthings etc. on the PC power plug, so you turn on the PC (via the plug that is connected to the Internet), wait until the PC boots up and then connect via RDP. When you are done, run in cmd `shutdown /h /t 0`, wait for a few minutes until the PC turns off and turn off the plug.