# Power on automatically after powercut?

Tags: linux, boot

Is it possible to power on a Linux machine automatically after powercut ? Without me
having to press the power button ?

Comment: That kind of control is in the BIOS, not in the OS.

Comment: You can use a UPS to both shut it down and subsequently start it back up.

Comment: Looks like ups is sort of like a back up battery of sort. It's charged from mains and kicks in to power the computer when there's a powercut. Is this it ?

Comment: Seems you talk about a physical linux box, just saying that VMs don't have a BIOS which would provide this functionality but usually can be set up in the VM Management part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something you can do using Linux, but rather what the BIOS is for.

In most BIOS versions there will be an option similar to "After power loss"
with possible values like *Power off* and *Reboot*.

If the BIOS lacks such an option,
you might possibly program your router to send a Wake-on-LAN packet on startup,
but that depends on [many factors](https://superuser.com/a/700246/8672).

Comment: I largely agree. That said, even if the BIOS does not have this functionality, it would still be possible to use something like an Arduino to initiate startup by emulating - or actually pressing - the on button. https://www.instructables.com/id/arduino-controlled-pc-power-switch/ has instructions for 1 such solution